# Google charts: identify a specific control

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there a way to identify which control in a set of bound controls is changed by the user?

In this instance I want to know that in a set of 5 bound controls, the user just changed control 3.

I want to resize the div that the control is within, based on the number of distinct values the user has chosen. I can get these, but I cannot identify which control has been changed.

So, something like:

```
 var controlPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            "controlType": "CategoryFilter",
            "containerId": "control1",
            "options": {
            "filterColumnLabel": "Media source",
            "ui": {
                "labelStacking": "horizontal",
                "allowTyping": true,
                "allowMultiple": true
            }
            }
        });

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

        barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            "chartType": "BarChart",
            "containerId": "chart_div",
            "options": {
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "120%",
            "vAxis": {title: "Media source (Branch - Dialled number)"},
            "hAxis": {title: "Number of calls"},
            "fontSize": 14,
            "chartArea": {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, height:"100%", width:"70%"}
            },
            "view": {"columns": [0,6,7,8,9,10,11]}
        });

        google.visualization.events.addListener(dashboard, "ready", function() {

                barChart.draw();

 resizeControl("control1", 50, barChart.getDataTable().getDistinctValues(1), 500);


            }

        });

        dashboard.bind(controlPicker1, controlPicker2);
        dashboard.bind(controlPicker2, controlPicker3);
        dashboard.bind(controlPicker3, controlPicker4);
        dashboard.bind(controlPicker4, controlPicker5);
        dashboard.bind(controlPicker5, barChart);
        dashboard.draw(view);
    }



    function resizeControl(name, total, div1, length) {
        var control=div1.length;
        if(total>control){
            var div=document.getElementById(name);
            var w=parseInt(div.style.width);
            var revs=($(this).width()/length);
            var newh = 35;
            for (var i=0; i <(control / revs); i++) {
                if(i>0)newh = newh+25;
            }
            newh + "px";
            $(div).height(newh);
        }
    }
```

Thanks,

H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a lot of information in your post. So I'll show you how to responder to a sort event in a Table.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort',
  function(event) {
    data.sort([{column: event.column, desc: !event.ascending}]);
    chart.draw(view);
  });
```

So depending on your chart type:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(map, 'select',
        function() {
          table.setSelection(map.getSelection());
        });
```

Find the event you want, add the listener to the chart.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the swift response. I've elabotated on the working code, however, I've stripped some out that isn't relevant to my question so it wouldn't execute. - I tried adding a select listener for the controlPicker1 control but nothing happens. I think it is because of the type of control I am working with and cannot find any online examples of adding en event for this control or an instance of this control if there are many. Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: It is the function call to `resizeControl` (which works as a function) which I need to isolate, based on the user changing `controlPickker1`

Comment: Try the statechange event:
Fired when the user interacts with the control, affecting its state. For example, a statechange event will fire whenever you move the thumbs of a range slider control. To retrieve an updated control state after the event fired, call ControlWrapper.getState().